# NSUserDefaults in iOS9 and XCode 7 does not return values

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I'm using NSUserDefaults to retrieve values. Like for example a user name.

I have created a **constants.h** file added it my viewcontroller like this

```
#import "constants.h"
```

In the constants.h  - Username is defined as

```
#define USERNAME @"Monty Python"
```

then in my viewDidLoad, I try and read the value like this

```
  NSString *userName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:USERNAME];
```

But userName is allway nil/null - so are my other keys.

How does NSUserDefaults know to use my Constants.h file? Is my code looking in the correct 'location'?  Why are my values always nil - both in the debugger and NSLog?

thx

Comment: You need to save a value in user defaults before retrieving it.

Comment: I guess you first set the object before checking for a result ?
Also, you just use a macro (#define) so NSUserDefault doesn't need to "know" constant file

Comment: If the code compiles then the reason is not the preprocessor macro `USERNAME` as constant

Comment: So you are trying to retrieve a string from user defaults? If so, what code do you use to save that string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Saving:

> [currentDefaults setObject:@"Jon" forKey:@"myName"];

Getting:

> [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"myName"]

Answer (score 5):

> How does NSUserDefaults know to use my Constants.h file?

It doesn't. There is no connection whatever between the two, and any expectation that there would be one is just wrong. Your *Constants.h* file configures some *global variables* in code, available to your other code as globals (provided that code imports that file). NSUserDefaults is a way of saving and retrieving a *.plist* file of *key-value pairs* on disk. They are totally different things, for totally different purposes.

In your code, you are using the *Constants.h* file as a way of supplying your code with the names of the *keys* to be used in NSUserDefaults. That is good practice! But this has nothing to do with how the *values* corresponding to those keys are going to get *into* NSUserDefaults in the first place.

The way to set "default defaults" (that is, initial values for each key-value pair to be kept in NSUserDefaults) — if that is what you're trying to do — is through code that runs very early and calls `registerDefaults:`.